# .net Core WebApi Content Negotiation

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying to add a CSV Output Formatter to my .NET Core 1.1 WebApi.

I've installed WebAPIContrib.Core package (https://github.com/damienbod/WebAPIContrib.Core/tree/master/src/WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Csv).

My Startup now look like this:

```
var csvFormatterOptions = new CsvFormatterOptions();
services.AddMvcCore(options =>
{
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CsvOutputFormatter(csvFormatterOptions));
    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("csv", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv"));
})
.AddJsonFormatters()
.AddJsonOptions(options => new SerializationHelper().Configure(options.SerializerSettings));
```

My controller method is completely generic and looks like this

```
[HttpGet("/api/export")]
[Produces("text/csv")]
public async Task<List<Data>> GetDataAsCsv()
{
    return await _someService.GetData();
}
```

My issue is that if i remove the produces attribute and don't send an accept header i still get a csv. How can he know to send back a CSV ? My other methods still produce JSON which is how it should be i just don't understand why this is and i'm afraid it will cause an issue down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Content negotiation is part of the framework but you would need to update the action to take advantage of this.

```
[HttpGet("/api/export")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData() {
    List<Data> data = await _someService.GetData();
    return Ok(data); // <-- returns OkObjectResult with content negotiation baked in
}
```

To quote the repo linked in the original post, look at the following from its [documentation](https://github.com/damienbod/WebAPIContrib.Core/tree/master/src/WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.Csv#documentation)

> The `Get` method exports the data using the Accept header in the HTTP
>   Request. Per default, Json will be returned. If the Accept Header is
>   set to 'text/csv', the data will be returned as csv. The `GetDataAsCsv`
>   method always returns csv data because the Produces attribute is used
>   to force this.

```
// GET api/csvtest
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() {
    return Ok(DummyData());
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("data.csv")]
[Produces("text/csv")]
public IActionResult GetDataAsCsv() {
    return Ok( DummyData());
}
```

Also as indicated in the documentation you should make sure you are configuring it properly in startup.

> Out of the box, ASP.NET Core only has Json (and possibly plain text)
>   as content types.

```
var csvOptions = new CsvFormatterOptions();
services.AddMvcCore(options => {
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
    })
    .AddJsonFormatters()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => new SerializationHelper().Configure(options.SerializerSettings))
    .AddCsvSerializerFormatters(csvOptions);
```

> Note that the call to `RespectBrowserAcceptHeader` is false by
>   default, so if you want content negotiation, you have to enable this.

Reference [Content Negotiation in ASP.NET Core](https://wildermuth.com/2016/03/16/Content_Negotiation_in_ASP_NET_Core)

Comment: I do not want to use AddMvc because it's a webApi and i don't need Razor. AddMvcCore can do exactly the same i just need to specify the services i want him to add. My problem is that if i *dont* specify an accept header and remove the produces attribute i still get a csv, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: Tried adding return Ok(_someService.GetData()) doesn't change anything. I still get a csv without the produces attribute and without an accept header.

Comment: Check the order you add the formatters. Also show one of the instances where JSON is returned

Comment: @Narcil also take a look at this article I found https://wildermuth.com/2016/03/16/Content_Negotiation_in_ASP_NET_Core